# How to express a 'smaller than or equals' relation in Knex.js

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

In my back-end I'm using KnexJS with PostgreSQL and I have to build a Knex function using its SQL builder without the raw SQL.

It is the first time for me to use KnexJS and I got few issues.

What I have to build is as shown in the SQL example

```
 UPDATE
     feed
  SET
     status = 'SOME_STATUS'
  WHERE
     created_at <= 'SOME_TIMESTAMP'
     AND conversation_id = 'ID';
```

This SQL is updating the table feed all columns with status and where two conditions are met.

In Knex what I tried as example code of my idea

```
answerPendingMessages(feeds) {
    return this.tx(tableName).where({
      conversationId,
      createdAt <= timestamp  // This not idea how to do in Knex ???
    }).update({
      status: 'ANSWERED'
    })
  }
```

In this above function my concern is how to actually convert the where part as one of the consitions is `createdAt <= 'TIMESTAMP'`

I understood that I can use where with an object but cannot understand how to include the `<=`

Also I should update the `updatedAt` column with the new timestamp but also that blocked me at the moment.

Te result in the end should that all columns which met the conditions are updated status to some some status and also a new updatedAt timestamp.

I'm not sure if there is a specific way with Knex to do so

Comment: If you are using PostreSQL why did you tag SQL Server?

Comment: I edited as was on suggested tags from the sytem actually that why i added

Comment: ...when you rewrite your question title to *"How to express a 'smaller than or equals' relation in Knex.js?"*, would you think you could find something based on that?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I'm always bad to write the correct asking

Comment: That was not my point. Do YOU think you can answer your question, now that it's clear what you are really asking? Because there is no way that you are the first person to have that problem, and there is no way that this is not explained in the documentation. So when you search for this, what comes up?

Comment: I'm adding my answer of what I want to achieve but is not working at the moment is actually not doing anything but is an example to understand than what is my goal

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to provide my goal for my previous question.
The script I'm showing is not doing anything and I don't know know to make it to work.

```
answerPendingMessages(feeds) {
    if (isEmpty(feeds)) return Promise.resolve([]);
    const { conversationId, createdAt } = feeds;
    return this.tx(tableName)
      .where(
        columns.conversationId === conversationId,
        columns.createdAt <= createdAt
      )
      .update({
        [columns.status]: 'ANSWERED',
        [columns.updatedAt]: new Date(),
      });
  }
```

What should happen here is that to update a table where I have two conditions but one of then is 'smaller than or equals' relation.

As the output of this should be that all rows where the 2 conditions are met are update status column.

Right now the script is not failing either success piratically nothing is happening.